# Vue.js (axios) ignoring Django Set-Cookie Response

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, cookies, django-rest-framework

I am migrating a Django project to Vue.js + DRF, because I need it to be SPA. I went into trouble regarding sessions and csrf cookie which is needed for obvious security reason.

Vue app runs on `127.0.0.1:8080`

DRF api runs on `127.0.0.1:8000`

Response headers used for request (AXIOS):

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,zh-CN;q=0.9,zh;q=0.8,es;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36
X-CSRFToken: undefined
```

Response headers from api:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 25
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2020 20:55:13 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.2
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=wFeB48cStoHy2hupKZNciGvYKFIlq4Y9QCfzCQ0Qfe5RMdRzolxcYK5MgefvLBcp; expires=Tue, 13 Jul 2021 20:55:13 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Vary: Accept, Cookie, Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

Expected outcome: The browser sets the cookie specified by the response headers.

I suspect the issue is due to the port being different, I found no solution but to build the Vue in the directory "dist" and Django serves the entry point, but that may not be what I want.

UPDATE: I tried setting the cookie domain to `127.0.0.1:8080`, doesn't work still.

Comment: Here's a very good project base to start from and links to others if you don't like the approach: https://github.com/danjac/django-vue-auth-demo - the primary advantage of this approach is that you don't need CORS and all it's ickyness.

Comment: is there another approach other than serving the front end from django ?

Comment: Sure, I've done it a few months ago. I can still remember the pain, not the details of what got it working. :D. But looking at the project, I installed [corsheaders](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) + did it's middleware, CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True and CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST. I used hostnames, not ip addresses.

Comment: @Melvyn I made it work using your CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS thing plus 1 more step ... before closing question, is using `withCredentials` from the client side vulnerable ?

Comment: I was also using that, but by that time I didn't care about security much. It does ring a bell that it was required for auth tokens to be accepted. I also used: `axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";` and `axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";`.

Comment: I am looking to put the auth token httponly, not sure if I can do that